# Type.GetProperties method gives empty array

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I have a class like this:

```
class ItemList
{
    Int64 Count { get; set; }
}
```

and when I write this:

```
ItemList list = new ItemList ( );
Type type = list.GetType ( );
PropertyInfo [ ] props = type.GetProperties ( );
```

I get an empty array for props.

Why? Is it because `GetProperties()` doesn't include automatic properties?

Comment: `To all who come from google:` if you still can't get your "properties" even after setting flags, if you're new to c# and don't know the difference between `Properties` and `Fields`, try using `GetFields()`. You've probably been looking for `fields` all along!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The problem is that GetProperties will only return Public properties by default.  In C#, members are not public by default (I believe they are internal).  Try this instead

```
var props = type.GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

The BindingFlags enumeration is fairly flexible.  The above combination will return all non-public instance properties on the type.  What you likely want though is all instance properties regardless of accessibility.  In that case try the following

```
var flags = BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic;
var props = type.GetProperties(flags);
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't realise that. Also how are you able to provide multiple options for a single argument? Are BindingFlags bits that you shift?

Comment: @Joan, yes.  BindingFlags is an enumeration which uses bit flags you can manipulate with |.  It's not providing multiple arguments, merely creating an enumeration value which has various bit combinations set.

Comment: Joan: Binding flags are a flags enum, so you can use | to pass multiple flags into the function.

Comment: For reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.flagsattribute.aspx